# AWS - Shared AMI (private)

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an account which shares an AMI with another account. My assumption is if we delete the source account, which shares the AMI with new account, the shared AMI is new account will not be available to use.

Is my assumption correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct.  Sharing an AMI only grants permission to another account to access it.  It doesn't make a copy, and if the first account deletes the AMI (or the account itself is deleted) then the AMI no longer exists for anyone.

But the other account can -- and, in most cases, probably *should* -- make a copy of the AMI and use the copy, instead.

> Copying a source AMI results in an identical but distinct target AMI with its own unique identifier. In the case of an Amazon EBS-backed AMI, each of its backing snapshots is, by default, copied to an identical but distinct target snapshot. (The one exception is when you choose to encrypt the snapshot.) You can change or deregister the source AMI with no effect on the target AMI. The reverse is also true.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/CopyingAMIs.html